# Вопрос по программированию на PHP. Про PDO

Tags: php, pdo

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что при повторной инициализации переменной с соединением пишет ошибку:

> Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2019] Can't initialize character set

Например так:

```
$categories = Category::getCategories();
$lastProds = Product::getLastProducts(3);
```

Классы `Category` и `Product`, их методы получают соединение так:

```
$db = DB::getConnection();
```

Класс `DB` и его метод просто возвращают объект `PDO`.

Как я заметил, исключение выкидывает, когда я открываю второе соединение:

```
$lastProds = Product::getLastProducts(3); //
```

Внутри этого метода если закоментировать получение соединения, то все вроде работает, но как мне получить два соединения?

Я все правильно понимаю?

Полный принт ошибки:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2019] Can't initialize character set (path: /Applications/MAMP/Library/share/charsets/)' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/components/DB.php:6
>   Stack trace: #0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/components/DB.php(6): PDO->__construct('mysql:dbname=;h...', NULL, NULL)
>     #1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/models/Product.php(5): DB::getConnection()
>     #2 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/controllers/SiteController.php(5): Product::getLastProducts(3)
>    #3 [internal function]: SiteController->actionIndex()
>    #4 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/components/Router.php(28): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
>    #5 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/index.php(12): Router->run()
>    #6 {main} thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/components/DB.php on line 6

---

Проблему решил, помог совет teran`а, а именно использование статических переменных класса.

Comment: во-первых, зачем вам открывать второе соединение, во-вторых, приведите код метода `DB::getConnection`, что-то меня напрягает строка `PDO->__construct` в логе

Comment: соединение, если оно идет к одной и той же БД с одними учетными данными создается один раз. Обычно для этого проще всего реализовать синглтон, используя статические переменные класса. То есть второй вызов `getConnection` не должен создавать новый объект PDO, а возвращать ранее созданный

Comment: Не совсем ответ на вопрос, но все же. Понимаю, что сейчас Вы пытаетесь реализовать MVC, причем, довольно криво (я уже понимаю, что для вас сейчас модель - это просто статичные функции и т.д., видел это подобие MVC). Посмотрите в сторону хороших фреймворков, таких, как laravel, yii, symphony и т.д., поскольку я на подобных "псевдо-MVC" просидел 3 месяца и очень об этом жалею